# How to find button element using webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, webdriver

I learning to write UI tests using Java and WebDriver.
Currently I'm having difficulties to find a button with the current XPATH:

```
//*[@id=':3e']/div/div
```

where id is changing dynamically. The HTML fragment for the button is:

```
    <div class="z0">
        <div class="T-I J-J5-Ji T-I-KE L3 T-I-JW T-I-JO" tabindex="0" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;" gh="cm">COMPOSE</div>
    </div>
```

I have created method for finding the element by class name "z0", but im facing issues when i want to click the button. I have tried with:

```
click();
sendkeys(Keys.Enter);
```

but i cannot click the element. Can anyone give me a clue?

Comment: Give the full html which is relevant to the question of yours and xpath...please. show the html part of this `[@id=':3e']`.. I need to see other attributes it has..Looking at the html you posted I can say you could use.. `//div[text()='COMPOSE']`...

Comment: Thanks Arup, `//div[text()='COMPOSE']` worked just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below **XPATH**

```
 //div[text()='COMPOSE']
```